# Avoid Django form being resubmitted by using HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: python, django

My views.py runs code fine when I press a button on my HTML page, views.py:

```
def start_or_end_fast(request):
   
  #If starting fast, add a row to the db:
  #fast_finished = False
  #start_date_time using = current time 
  #end_date_time using = current time 
  if request.method == 'POST' and 'start_fast' in request.POST:
    add_fast = logTimes(fast_finished=False,start_date_time=datetime.now(),end_date_time=datetime.now())
    add_fast.save()
    print(add_fast.start_date_time,add_fast.end_date_time) 
    print('Fast started')
    #return render(request,'startandstoptimes/index.html')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('startandstoptimes/index.html')
```

You can see my commented return line, this works but when I refresh the page I can resubmit the data, I want to avoid this. In researching my solution, I saw this could be solved using HttpResponseRedirect but I am not able to get this to work with my code, the more I change the more broken things become.

My application urls.py:

```
from turtle import home
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.start_or_end_fast,name="start_or_end_fast")
]
```

My project urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('startandstoptimes.urls'))
]
```

I believe it is related to the URLs, due to the 404 message I see:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/startandstoptimes/index.html
Using the URLconf defined in myfastingsite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='start_or_end_fast']
The current path, startandstoptimes/index.html, didn’t match any of these.
```

Am I going down the right route trying to use HttpResponseRedirect or is there a better solution?

Comment: `HttpResponseRedirect()` takes a url.  You aren't passing it a url -- you're passing the name of  a template.  Those are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> class HttpResponseRedirect¶
>
> The first argument to the constructor is required – the path to redirect to. This can be a fully qualified URL (e.g.
> 'https://www.yahoo.com/search/'), an absolute path with no domain
> (e.g. '/search/'), or even a relative path (e.g. 'search/'). In that
> last case, the client browser will reconstruct the full URL itself
> according to the current path. See HttpResponse for other optional
> constructor arguments. Note that this returns an HTTP status code 302.

See this link for more details: [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/)

As what the documentation says, HttpResponseRedirect accepts URL and not the path of your template. You should be doing it something like this:

```
 from django.urls import reverse
 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('start_or_end_fast'))
```

Comment: That worked thank you and thanks for the link to the docs, I need to dedicate time to reviewing these.